# re-arrange xml elements using pentaho

Tags: xml, pentaho

I have an xml input as show below

```
<setAdmin Id="2">
   <Type>7</Type>    
   <size>40</size>    
   <assets>    
      <asset id="24">    
         <entity>PNR</entity>    
      </asset>    
   </assets>    
</setAdmin>
```

Output required is

```
<setAdmin Id="2">       
   <assets>    
      <asset id="24">    
         <entity>PNR</entity>    
      </asset>    
   </assets>    
   <Type>7</Type>    
   <size>40</size>    
</setAdmin>
```

I'm novice to pentaho. But I tried using select icon, but it is not working. Please help.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do it:
 - you can read nodes with the "Get data from XML" specifiyng the result type as "Single node" and than combine the results as a text
- you can use JavaScript to manipulate XML nodes
- you can use Regex
- etc.

But the most convinient and correct way to do it - use XSLT transformation as @astro11 proposes in his answer

Answer (score 3):

You could use the **XSL Transformation** step to manipulate your XML.

> XSL stands for EXtensible Stylesheet Language, and is a style sheet
>   language for XML documents.

Assuming that your XML is that simple and you only want to make these specific changes, you could create a xsl file with the following code:

```
<xsl:template match="setAdmin">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="assets" />
     <xsl:apply-templates select="Type" />
     <xsl:apply-templates select="size" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This will require that your XML file/content is stored in one single row. You can achieve that with the **Load file content in memory** step. Finally, after the manipulation is done, you'll have a result column with the transformed XML. You can use a simple **Text file output** to save your new XML (remember to not include the header).

Your transformation will look like this:

[image]